# Why is list of type TObjectList freed automatically after iteration?

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I have a question regarding the behaviour of the TObjectList class of the Spring4D framework. In my code I create a list of geometric figures such as `square`, `circle`, `triange`, each defined as an individual class. To free the geometric figures automatically when the list gets destroyed I defined a list of type TObjectList like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  geometricFigures: TObjectList<TGeometricFigure>;
  geometricFigure: TGeometricFigure;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;

  geometricFigures := TObjectList<TGeometricFigure>.Create();
  try
    geometricFigures.Add(TCircle.Create(4,2));
    geometricFigures.Add(TCircle.Create(0,4));
    geometricFigures.Add(TRectangle.Create(3,10,4));
    geometricFigures.Add(TSquare.Create(1,5));
    geometricFigures.Add(TTriangle.Create(5,7,4));
    geometricFigures.Add(TTriangle.Create(2,6,3));

    for geometricFigure in geometricFigures do begin
      geometricFigure.ToString();
    end;
  finally
    //geometricFigures.Free(); -> this line is not required (?)
  end;
end;
```

If I run this code the list `geometricFigures` is freed automatically from memory even if I am not calling the method `Free` on the list (notice commented out line in the finally block). I expected a different behaviour, I thought the list needs an explicit call to Free() because the local variable `geometricFigures` is not using an interface type.

I further noticed that if the items of the list are not iterated in the for-in loop (I removed it from the code temporarily), the list is not freed automatically and i get a memory leak.

This leads me to the following question:
Why is the list of type TObjectList (`geometricFigures`) freed automatically  when its items are iterated but not if the for-in loop is removed from the code?

#### Update

I followed the advice of Sebastian and debugged the destructor. The list items get destroyed by the following code:

```
{$REGION 'TList<T>.TEnumerator'}

constructor TList<T>.TEnumerator.Create(const list: TList<T>);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fList := list;
  fList._AddRef;
  fVersion := fList.fVersion;
end;

destructor TList<T>.TEnumerator.Destroy;
begin
  fList._Release;
  inherited Destroy; // items get destroyed here
end;
```

#### Update

I had to reconsider my accepted answer and came to the following conclusion:

In my opinion Rudy's answer is correct even though the described behaviour might not be a bug in the framework. I think Rudy makes a good argument by pointing out that a framework should work as expected. When I am using a for-in loop I expect it to be a read-only operation. Clearing the list afterwards is not what I expected to happen.

On the other hand Fritzw and David Heffernan are pointing out that the design of the Spring4D framework is interface based and therefore should be used in that way. As long as this behaviour is documented (maybe Fritzw could give us a reference to the documentation) I agree with David that my usage of the framework is not correct even though I still think that the behaviour of the framework is missleading.

I am not experienced enough in developing with Delphi to evaluate if the described behaviour is actually a bug or not therefore revoked my accepted answer, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand **why** the list is freed we need to understand what is going on behind the scenes.

`TObjectList<T>` is designed to use as an interface and has reference counting. Whenever the refcount reaches 0 the instance will be freed.

```
procedure foo;
var
  olist: TObjectList<TFoo>;
  o: TFoo;
begin
  olist := TObjectList<TFoo>.Create();
```

The refcount for `olist` is now at 0

```
  try
    olist.Add( TFoo.Create() );
    olist.Add( TFoo.Create() );

    for o in olist do
```

The enumerator increase the refcount of `olist` to 1

```
    begin
      o.ToString();
    end;
```

The enumerator get out of scope and the destructor of the enumerator is called, which will decrease the refcount of `olist` to 0, and that implies that the `olist` instance is freed.

```
  finally
    //olist.Free(); -> this line is not required (?)
  end;
end;
```

## What is the difference when using an interface variable?

```
procedure foo;
var
  olist: TObjectList<TFoo>;
  olisti: IList<TFoo>;
  o: TFoo;
begin
  olist := TObjectList<TFoo>.Create();
```

`olist` refcount is 0

```
  olisti := olist;
```

Assigning the `olist` reference to the interface variable `olisti` will internally call `_AddRef` on `olist` and increase the refcount to 1.

```
  try
    olist.Add( TFoo.Create() );
    olist.Add( TFoo.Create() );

    for o in olist do
```

The enumerator increase the refcount of `olist` to 2

```
    begin
      o.ToString();
    end;
```

The enumerator get out of scope and the destructor of the enumerator is called, which will decrease the refcount of `olist` to 1.

```
  finally
    //olist.Free(); -> this line is not required (?)
  end;
end;
```

At the end of the procedure the interface variable `olisti` will be set to `nil`, which will internally call `_Release` on `olist` and decrease the refcount to 0 and that implies that the `olist` instance is freed.

### The same happens when we assign the reference direct from constructor to the interface variable:

```
procedure foo;
var
  olist: IList<TFoo>;
  o: TFoo;
begin
  olist := TObjectList<TFoo>.Create();
```

Assigning the reference to the interface variable `olist` will internally call `_AddRef` and increase the refcount to 1.

```
  olist.Add( TFoo.Create() );
  olist.Add( TFoo.Create() );

  for o in olist do
```

The enumerator increase the refcount of `olist` to 2

```
  begin
    o.ToString();
  end;
```

The enumerator get out of scope and the destructor of the enumerator is called, which will decrease the refcount of `olist` to 1.

```
end;
```

At the end of the procedure the interface variable `olist` will be set to `nil`, which will internally call `_Release` on `olist` and decrease the refcount to 0 and that implies that the `olist` instance is freed.

Answer (score 9):

To do an iteration with `for ... do`, the class must have a `GetEnumerator` method. This obviously returns itself (i.e. the `TObjectList<>`) as an `IEnumerator<TGeometricFigure>` **interface**. After the iteration, the `IEnumerator<>` is released, its reference count reaches 0, and the objectlist is freed.

This is a pattern you often see in, say, C#, but there, it doesn't have this effect, because the class instance is still referenced and the garbage collector will not jump in.

In Delphi however, this is a problem, as you can see. I guess the solution would be for the `TObjectList<>` to have a separate (possibly nested) class or record that does the enumeration, and not to return `Self` (as `IEnumerator<>`). But this is up to the author of Spring4D. You could bring this problem to the attention of Stefan Glienke.

#### Update

Your addendum shows that this is not exactly what happens. The `TObjectList<>` (or to be more precise, its ancestor `TList<>`) returns a separate enumerator, but that does an (IMO totally unnecessary, even if the list is used as interface from the start) `_AddRef`/`_Release` and the latter is the culprit.

#### Note

I see multiple claims that in Spring4D, the class should not be used as class. Then such classes should not be exposed in the `interface` section, but in the `implementation` section of the unit instead. If such classes are exposed, the author should expect the user to use them. And if they are usable as class, then a `for-in` loop should not free the container. One of these is a design problem: either the exposure as class, or the auto-freeing. So there is a bug, IMO.

Comment: It seems to me that this is exactly what is happening. Do I understand you correctly that this could be described as a bug?

Comment: Yes, if this is what happens, it is very likely a bug in the `TObjectList<>`provided by Spring4D.

Comment: Spring4d is designed to use the interfaces not the classes. It is not a Bug it is as designed and documented

Comment: Defect is in the code in the question, framework is fine, behaves as designed

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. The _AddRef and _Release are the cause, and that should not happen. A for-in over a container should never trigger freeing the container, so obviously the framework does not behave as expected (no matter if it behaves as designed). It violates the principle of least astonishment, if not more.

Comment: @Fritzw: if Spring4D exposes the classes as well, then they should be usable as such too. And then a for-in should not free the container. If they should only be used as interfaces, then the classes should not be exposed. And anyway, I don't quite see why the _AddRef and _Release are in the respective constructor and destructor of the enumerator at all.

Comment: @David - A defect in a design is still a defect.  The fact that the code (in the framework) has an implementation that is consistent with the defect in the design does not alter the fact that it is a bug.  This is software quality 101 V&V - Verification (against specification) is only half of a fitness test.  The other half is Validation, that the specification was correct in the first place.  "As designed" is a valid response only when the design itself is verified and validated as correct.  In this case it quite clearly is not.

Comment: @Deltics TInterfacedObject has the same behaviour. Publically exposed.how else can you inherit from it. You are naive if you think that library design can stop consumers making mistakes.

Comment: @Rudy I don't agree, "Never" mix classes and interfaces. The whole Design is Interface based, so use it these way. In these special case i think the reason for the _addref and _release is the possibility to have "lazy" enumerations. Read the Doc

Comment: If this is a bug, then all properties, which type is inherited from TObject, are also buggy, because you can easily call `TFoo.Bar.Free` to destroy the Bar property instance and leave a dangling pointer on it. Or is it just a "don't do this"?

Comment: I also don't understand why `_AddRef`/`_Release` were used in the enumerator's constructor and destructor. They should be removed IMO, and `fList` should be treated as a weak reference.

Comment: @Fritzw could you please give us a reference to the documentation you pointed out

Comment: The _addref and _release are needed because of the IEnumerable<T>. There is a need to hold the Data alive for the lifetime of the Interface. And again the whole spring4d is designed or use as Interfaces. If you need a Generic List as class use the Generics and not Spring4d

Comment: Can someone explain to me why the list is freed after iteration when using TObjectList<T> but not if the list variable is declared as an interface IList<T>? Shouldn't there occur the same problem.

Comment: @MUG4N if you use an interface reference instead of an instance reference, then an instance refcount is incremented by 1, and that solves the problem with reference counting.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: TInterfacedObject does not expose a GetEnumerator, so that is irrelevant. And it does not free itself when it is only used *as class* (if anyone would want to).

Comment: @Fritzw: I know that one should never mix class and interface references unless you know exactly what you do. So generally, don't do it. I have absolutely no clue how that is relevant here, though. Here, the object list is **only referenced as class instance**, i.e. there is no mix, and then it should not be auto-freed.

Comment: @Fritzw: It is never a good idea to free (or nil) the container that is currently enumerated. That is simply undefined behaviour. **Protecting** against such behaviour is however silly and unnecessary. It is just as silly as trying to protect against properties being freed, as SirRufo already said.

Comment: @Rudy You really don't understand any of this at all. TInterfacedObject breaks your bogus rule. You don't need an enumerator in the class here for the code to be wrong. You must take a reference to an interface when the class has lifetime managed this way.

Comment: @user246408: That is what I am saying too. I assume it is to ensure that the enumerated list is not freed (indirectly, through nilling the reference) during the enumeration. But that is not necessary, IMO. It is unnecessary defensiveness, and in the end, it can cause the object list to be freed (as in the question).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I fully understand it. I also understand why the `_AddRef` and `_Release` are used (to avoid that the container is freed during the numeration). But trying to avoid that is plain silly, just as silly as trying to avoid that a user frees a class you provide (say, as parameter). If a user nils the `IList<T>` reference he has during enumeration, that is plain stupid and **his or her problem**, not the responsibility of the designer. The `_AddRef` and `_Release` don't belong there.

Comment: @David: TInterfacedObject breaks what "bogus rule"? Classes that are usable without interface reference should not assume that they are used as interfaces. Not even TInterfacedObject does that (it will not free itself if not used as interface), although that is specifically made to implement interfaces.

Comment: @rudy wrong. TInterfacedObject does destroy itself when ref count goes to zero. Simply put you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @rudy The whole thing for Spring4d: It is designed to use it the "interface" way. There is no problem if there is no mix between class and interface use. This discussion is not necessary if the Library is used as designed.

Comment: @Fritzw: That may be the intent of the designer, but that doesn't mean a class should fail if not used the **normal** way. In the question **there is no mix between class and interface**. The class is never used as interface. If the design intent is that the class is only used as interface, then it should not be made usable as class.

Comment: If TInterfacedObject is used **as class instance only**, as the object list in the question is, then it will never be refcounted so it will not free itself. I know that TInterfacedObject does nothing useful in and of itself, but it does not free itself if not referenced as interface. But the object list discussed does, and that is a bug.

Comment: And I do know what I am talking about. I am fully aware of how refcounting for interfaces works. But a class that implements an interface, **if it is not used from an interface reference**, should not free itself, because it is **never refcounted**, unless someone is so stupid to do it manually, using _AddRef and _Release. Note that the object list in the question **is not used as interface**, so it should never be refcounted (and certainly not by its own enumerator).

Comment: my last post to these discussion. We are talking about Spring4d: The Documentation ist starting with: 
**Welcome to the Spring for Delphi wiki! Spring4D is a Delphi-based framework that contains a number of different modules including:
A set of interface-based Collections
A powerful IEnumerable<T> interface for accessing those collections
We can always discuss the academic way like freeandnil but for me it is clear : Use the Library as designed and it will work.

Comment: @Fritzw: A class, even if it implements an interface, even if it is intended to be used as interface, should not (directly or indirectly) free itself **if it is not used as interface**. If it should not be used normally, i.e. only as interface, then the designer should not expose the class. Using a class directly, i.e. not as interface, should **never** cause a class to free itself, because it should never be refcounted (as interface-- let's disregard the mobile compilers for now). You can discuss about the usefulness of such a class, but that is irrelevant to this **bug**.

Comment: @Fritzw: Using FreeAndNil is not the academic way. It is actually hardly ever needed and very often used when it is not necessary at all, as some misunderstood way of "defensive programming".

Comment: Again, if a class can be instantiated as class instance, and it is never referenced as interface, then it should not be refcounted like an interface, and certainly not by its own enumerator. It seems to me that you and others don't understand that. The _Release and _AddRef are simply unncessary.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: This discussion has gone *beyond* civilised. I suggest you both read http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice and walk away.

Comment: I just ran in the same problem. If you insert spring.collections.lists in the uses class, all classes that inherited from TList<T> broke on enumerations that worked before fine with generics.collections.

Comment: btw: replacing TList<T> with a TList<T> that behaves completely different is burning down the liskov substitution principle. At least rename it.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a `for in loop` to iterate trough the collection; that kind of loop looks for a method in the class called `GetEnumerator`. In Spring4D, for a `TObjectList<T>`, you end up calling the inherited `TList<T>.GetEnumerator`, which is implemented as:

```
function TList<T>.GetEnumerator: IEnumerator<T>;
begin
  Result := TEnumerator.Create(Self);
end;
```

And the constructor for `TEnumerator` is implemented as:

```
constructor TList<T>.TEnumerator.Create(const list: TList<T>);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fList := list;
  fList._AddRef;
  fVersion := fList.fVersion;
end;
```

Note that it will call `_AddRef` on the list. At that point, your `TObjetList` `RefCount` goes to 1

Since the `GetEnumerator` call returns an interface, when you finish looping it will get Freed. The `Destructor` is implemented like this:

```
destructor TList<T>.TEnumerator.Destroy;
begin
  fList._Release;
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Note that it calls `_Release` on the list. If you step in using the debugger, you will note that it decrements the `RefCount` of the list to 0 and then it calls `_Release`, so thats why your list is being freed

If you remove the for in loop in your original code, you will end up with a memory leak:

---

### Unexpected Memory Leak

An unexpected memory leak has occurred. The unexpected small block leaks are:

1 - 12 bytes: TGeometricFigure x 6, TMoveArrayManager x 1, Unknown x 1

21 - 28 bytes: TList x 1

29 - 36 bytes: TCriticalSection x 1

53 - 60 bytes: TCollectionChangedEventImpl x 1, Unknown x 1

77 - 84 bytes: TObjectList x 1

Edit: just saw Rudy Velthuis answer. This is not a Spring4D bug. You should **not** use the frameworks class-based collections. You **must** use the interface based collections. Also, not related to Spring4D, but in Delphi, you are advised not to mix interface references with object references

Comment: If the class-based collections should not be used, then they should not be exposed (they should be declared and implemented in the implementation section only). If a class is exposed, the author should expect it to be used. And if the class can be used, it should not free itself in a `for-in` loop. So I consider it a design bug, either because these classes are exposed when they should not be, or because the enumerator frees the container. One of these should not happen.

Comment: The enumerator does not free the container. The enumerator increases the RefCount when it recieves the container, and the decrements it again when it let's it go. The enumerator expects the container to be properly initialized: not recieving an Interfaced Object with a RefCount of Zero.

Also, if you put the class in the implementation section, how would you be able to create one of the and expose the interface? How could Spring.Collections.TCollections.CreateList access the TObjectList?

Comment: @rudy Have you any experience with Delphi interfaces? I mean real world experience.

Comment: @rudy Hiding interface implementing classes in implementation section solves nothing and will call only trouble (for testing, inheritance, ...). Also it will not keep away the programmer to cast the interface reference to TObject and f.i. free that instance. So it is worth nothing

Comment: Why is the code behaving differently when declaring the list variable as IList<T> instead of the TObjectList<T>? As far as I can see the same code is executed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes, I have a lot of real world experience with Delphi interfaces. Why do you ask?

Comment: @SirRufo: If the list is only designed to be used as interface, then hiding the implementation ensures that the implementing class is not used as class. These days, one can cast the interface to the implementing class again, but if this is not public, then to what should the interface be cast?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis If it is not public, how will you inherit from it? How will you test exactly that implementation? If hidden you have to rely on something that will maybe return that class for testing. I don't like that kind of hiding, because it forces more trouble than it does really help

Comment: There's not a lot of point arguing with Rudy here. He clearly doesn't understand the issues.

Comment: I do understand what you are saying. But I don't agree. A class that is instatiable directly, i.e. without using an interface reference, should be able to function as-is, and it should not free itself. But even if the class is meant to *only* serve as implementation of an interface, then the manual `_AddRef` and `_Release` in the enumerator are completely unnecessary. That is a bug, no matter how long you argue I don't understand the issue. I do, but I disagree. If the class is exposed, it should be usable as is. Otherwise, it should be made impossible for the user to instantiate it directly.

Comment: I won't argue with you.

Answer (score 3):

Spring4D's collection classes are designed to be use with interfaces, TObjectList implements IList, so you if you reference it using the interface it will work as expected.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  geometricFigures: IList<TGeometricFigure>;
  geometricFigure: TGeometricFigure;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;

  geometricFigures := TCollections.CreateObjectList<TGeometricFigure>(true);
  geometricFigures.Add(TCircle.Create(4,2));
  geometricFigures.Add(TCircle.Create(0,4));
  geometricFigures.Add(TRectangle.Create(3,10,4));
  geometricFigures.Add(TSquare.Create(1,5));
  geometricFigures.Add(TTriangle.Create(5,7,4));
  geometricFigures.Add(TTriangle.Create(2,6,3));

  for geometricFigure in geometricFigures do 
  begin
    geometricFigure.ToString();
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own TGemoetricFigures List that overrides the destructor. Then you can tell pretty quickly who is calling the destructor.

```
type
  TGeometricFigures = class(TObjectList<TGeometricFigure>)
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TGeometricFigures }

destructor TGeometricFigures.Destroy;
begin
  ShowMessage('TGeometricFigures.Destroy was called');
  inherited;
end;

procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  geometricFigures: TGeometricFigures;
  geometricFigure: TGeometricFigure;
begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;

  geometricFigures := TGeometricFigures.Create;
  try
    geometricFigures.Add(TCircle.Create(4,2));
    geometricFigures.Add(TCircle.Create(0,4));
    geometricFigures.Add(TRectangle.Create(3,10,4));
    geometricFigures.Add(TSquare.Create(1,5));
    geometricFigures.Add(TTriangle.Create(5,7,4));
    geometricFigures.Add(TTriangle.Create(2,6,3));

    for geometricFigure in geometricFigures do begin
      geometricFigure.ToString();
    end;
  finally
    //geometricFigures.Free(); -> this line is not required (?)
  end;
end;
```

My guess is that something inside of geometricFigure.ToString() does something something that should not happen that as a side effect destroys geometricFigues. Use the FastMM4 FullDebugMode, and it is likely that you will get more info.

Comment: `ToString()` is not the problem (it would have surprised me if it were anyway). The problem is the `_AddRef` in the constructor and the `_Release` in the destructor of the enumerator. Both are, AFAICT, unnecessary, but the `_Release` is what brings the refcount to 0 and then frees the entire class.